# Orientdb memory/speed settings

Tags: performance, memory, indexing, orientdb

I have an OrientDB graph database. Some of the class types are pretty large (i.e. > 60M) some are somewhat smaller. Orient is pretty fast on searching, when indexed.
Some of the properties I indexed are running at near 100K/s, while some other start at 5K/s then slow towards 10/s. 
This, for a part, is due to the settings maxHeap and bufferSize.
I could not find a helpful page on how to compute the server.bat/sh settings for indexing certain types of data.

Anybody got experience on indexing large ( >>10M) items?
Do I have to reboot the server each time I index a large set, or start creating edges? Does the index-type matter wrt indexing speed?

Comment: I must say, up to now, it seems that when indexing, keep -Xmx <512M (pref -+256M), Dstorage.diskCache.bufferSize to no more than 8G. I was not aware the 'bufferSize' is storage in RAM.